# global variable not accessible to methods when used with testing

Tags: go, runtime-error, panic

I am facing problem while using `Golang` Testing.Global variable not accessible to methods.
Following is the code snippet

test1.go

```
var map1 = make(map[string]string)

func f()(req *http.Request) (ismime bool, map1 map[string]string, err 
error) {
 map1["key"]="value"
return true,map1,nil
}
```

I am getting following errors

> `panic: assignment to entry in nil map [recovered]`
>
> `panic: assignment to entry in nil map`

Comment: You've shadowed the global map1 by your function definition.

Comment: @DenysSéguret how do i make it work if i just want to return it with return statement??i.e instead of using return true,map1,nil can I use only return

Comment: @nikhil You cannot. Not doable, don't try. Redesign.

Comment: @nikhil hard to explain in comment so I make an answer. I'll delete it if I didn't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: why question is downvoted?

Comment: @nikhil I didn't downvote but I can guess 2 reasons. **1)** you posted an unformated code (always use go format before asking) **2)** the design of your code is suspect

Comment: @nikhil Two more reason: 3) The title is missleading as the problem is completely unrelated to testing for whatever definition of testing and 4) Shadowing is normal in Go but shadowing a global with a named return is obvious a no go.

Comment: One more reason: your code doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments it looks like you didn't really want to shadow the global variable `map1`, you just want to return it.

So you probably want

```
func f()(req *http.Request) (bool, map[string]string, error) {
    map1["key"]="value"
    return true, map1, nil
}
```

Returning three arguments, and a global variable among them, looks strange though. There's probably something ill designed.